# There is no sound on my HP Pavilion 15 4RN**** with B&O on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, hp, hp-pavilion

After I installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion 15 4RN****, there was no sound.

I didn't find any solutions online.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?